# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Adaptive Keyboard (Gen 2)

Tags: drivers, keyboard, lenovo, thinkpad

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon, and it has a touch sensitive adaptive keyboard and fingerprint sensor. The laptop came with Windows 8, and after I installed Windows 10, the adaptive keyboard stopped functioning. A couple of months later (June 2017),  they came out with a driver for the adaptive keyboard which I downloaded and it worked.

However, I am not happy with Windows. I have started doing some simple video editing on OpenShot, and the software freezes often. I would like to switch to Ubuntu Budgie now.

Is it possible to download this software and have the adaptive keyboard working? How about the fingerprint sensor (which I never use anyway)?

If not Ubuntu Budgie, then what other Ubuntu software can I use?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Any Ubuntu flavor has the exact same hardware support out of the box and the exact same ability to install the (same) additional drivers if needed. So, your choice should be according to your personal preference regarding the different desktop environments available. I cannot say the "adaptive keyboard" will work, I don't even know what that is, TBH. Most fingerprint readers are supported but additional software is often required.

Comment: Hi! The adaptive keyboard does work! Thank you for your Response! There were three different modes, but two are working (Fn keys and volume/brightness,etc.). But that is all that I need. I don't even remember what was on the third settings. :D